# remove - disable memcached ubuntu

Tags: mysql, apache, memcached

Hello I have problems to know if memcached is disable or not. I will like disable memcached to install xcache. There are a lot of tutorials to install but nothing to unistall

My system is ubuntu 12, the file of conf is in etc folder.

```
vi /etc/memcached.conf
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 15):

This will remove just the memcached package itself.

```
sudo apt-get remove memcached
```

This will remove the memcached package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove memcached
```

try this may it help you .

Comment: Hello Thank you. I realease this but I see in php.ini the memcache

Comment: you welcome my friend @virtualsets . i am not sure how to remove from php.ini ,let me check before then i am info you .Thank you

Comment: If you also want to delete your local/config files for memcached then this will work. is it ?

Comment: i am not sure but you can try this [sudo apt-get purge memcached]

Comment: The problems is that I dont know if it is disable. I see in php.ini and see with "ps aux | grep memcached". Thks

Answer (score 1):

```
apt -y remove memcached
apt -y remove php-memcached
systemctl restart phpX.Y-fpm
```

X.Y = php version (for example: php7.4-fpm).